# How to get last day payment failed transaction list using authorize.net node JS?

Tags: node.js, authorize.net

I'm using authorize.net node SDK for create ARB, now i want to get list of payment failed transaction list of last day, authorize.net node SDK provider any built in way for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list of failed transactions you need to make an API call to the [Transaction Reporting API -> Get Transaction List endpoint](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#transaction-reporting-get-transaction-list). It will contain a list of transactions and their status code. You can then look for all transactions with a response code of `2` which is declined.